# Select text between two paterns in huge html file?

Tags: grep, sh

1st issue : My code is working only if grep take constant pattern like this :

```
echo "$s" | grep -oP '(?<=class="A3">).*(?=</a>)'
```

2nd issue : assigning output to a variable not working too

Here is my script :

```
#!/bin/sh

filename="data.txt"
Ptr_ValidChannel="><a title=\"Id: "
Ptr_ChannelNameStart="<class=\"A3\">"
Ptr_ChannelNameEnd="</a>"
while read -r line
do
    case "$line" in
        # working 100%
        #*$Ptr_ValidChannel*) echo "$line" | grep -oP '(?<=class="A3">).*?(?=</a>)' ;; 

        # not working
        #*$Ptr_ValidChannel*) echo $line | grep -oP '(?<=$Ptr_ChannelNameStart).*?(?=$Ptr_ChannelNameEnd)' ;;

        # not working
        *$Ptr_ValidChannel*) myvar=$(echo $line | grep -oP '(?<=$Ptr_ChannelNameStart).*?(?=$Ptr_ChannelNameEnd)') ;; 

    esac

done < "$filename"

echo $var_name

exit
```

To simplify things the data.txt content is :

```
    <TD WIDTH="15%"><a title="Id: I24 NEWS" class="A3">I24 News Français</a><br /><font color="#555555"> <a title="Sporadic or full 16/9 transmission"><img src="/169.gif"></a>
```

In my system the command :

```
 ls -la /bin/sh
```

output is :

```
  /bin/sh -> dash
```

best regards.

PS. NO BASH CODE PLEASE. ONLY SH.

Comment: Please read this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/867395

Comment: Use an XML parser like `xmllint`.

Comment: I'm not looking to make an html parser, i just want to extract some data using a subset html tags.

Comment: second question resolved by putting the ? after the * quantifier :       echo "$s" | grep -oP '(?<=class="A3">).*?(?=</a>)'

Comment: Not very clear what you mean. Your `grep` works to me. To be more sure you don't catch the rest of the line, you can use `grep -oP '(?<=class="A3">)[^<]*(?=</a>)'`

Comment: i want to pass the 2 variables patterns to grep and catch the output in a new variable for later use.          *$Ptr_ValidChannel*) var_name=$(echo $line | grep -oP '(?<=$Ptr_ChannelNameStart).*?(?=Ptr_ChannelNameEnd)') ;;  then var_name must contain the value "I24 News Français"

Comment: i modified the code to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

After reading this article: [dash as bin sh.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) i figured out what to do to make my code work correctly and more portable:

```
#! /bin/sh

filename='data.txt'
Ptr_ValidChannel='><a title="Id: '
Ptr_ChannelNameStart='class="A3">'
Ptr_ChannelNameEnd='</a>'
while read -r line
do
case "$line" in
    *"$Ptr_ValidChannel"*) var_name=$(printf %s "$line" | grep -oP '(?<='"$Ptr_ChannelNameStart"').*?(?='"$Ptr_ChannelNameEnd"')'); printf %s "$var_name"; printf '\n'; ;;
esac

done < "$filename"
exit
```

Thank you for your comments

best reagrds.